# Como crear atributos personalizados en LDAP con ApacheDirectoryStudio?

Tags: apache, ldap, openldap

Soy Nuevo en LDAP, Necesito crear un campo el cual permita guardar la fecha de nacimiento de un usuario!! estoy trabajando con ApacheDirectoryStudio. ya he mirado varios ejemplos pero no me funcionan.

Comment: Hola Hembert Iregui, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, saludos!

Comment: Gracias por el interés este es el ejemplo que sigo https://www.terena.org/mail-archives/tf-emc2/msg00144.html    y lo quiero replicar con las Herramientas que salen el la guia de usuario http://directory.apache.org/studio/users-guide/schema_editor/gettingstarted_editors_attribute_type.html . Sigo todos los pasos de Crear: schema project, schema, nuevo atributo y la clase. pero al final no consigo ni los atributos ni la clase que cree.